# WebSphere 9 upgrade with RAD 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-rad

Our developers currently use the IBM RAD 8.5 to develop web applications (No enterprise Java beans (No J2EE), use Spring framework). The server team is planning to upgrade WebSphere from version 8 to version 9.  Last I checked in the servers tab, RAD 8.5 supports WAS version 8, 8.5, and 8.5 Liberty profile. See screenshot.

[image: RAD 8.5 supported WAS servers]

Is it possible to continue to develop in RAD 8.5, and deploy to WebSphere 9 in the server environment?  What kind of snag would I expect to run into?  e.g. Assemble the WAR file in RAD 8.5, and deploy the WAR file in WAS 9.

Would there be any problem I should anticipate in the deployment descriptor?  e.g. files like web.xml and application.xml?

Moving forward, is it better to use other IDE to do software development if we are not planning to upgrade RAD 8.5 to a newer version?  Would MyEclipse(variant of Eclipse with better server support) or Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  (oxygen) suffice? Do I also need the liberty profile?
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/

What kind of issues should I be expecting?  Or continue using RAD 8.5 would be a better option?

Here are some of the stackoverflow links I had checked already.  There are pretty high level.

[what-are-the-differences-when-deploying-on-tomcat-vs-websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520293/what-are-the-differences-when-deploying-on-tomcat-vs-websphere)

[can-a-war-file-be-deployed-on-any-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642696/can-a-war-file-be-deployed-on-any-server)

Thanks.

Comment: Have a similar situation but will try to upgrade RAD 9.1. May i ask is there any specific reason you dont want to move to RAD 9?

Comment: it is a corporate environment, and they want to cut cost by not upgrading RAD.

Comment: In case anyone need something similar, after lots of trial and error installing rad 9,  I succeed with Eclipse Neon with was9 plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I could not use RAD 8.5 to control a v9 server.  I could not use Java 8 in RAD 8.5.  I would not expect RAD 8.5 to know about the newer versions of JPA, JAX-RS and other things in v9. You could continue to develop jee6 apps on a v8.5 server and then move them manually to a v9 server.

Liberty is worth a look but is not completely interchangeable.  Liberty has features that traditional does not (MicroProfile) and lacks some older things that traditional has (JAX-RPC).

You might check out the WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse that have support for traditional v9.  They're not as full featured as RAD but might be enough.  More info is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/wdt_overview.htm

Comment: updated link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_eclipse.htm

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the information provided by Bruce, IBM had introduced OpenLiberty where one can deploy the war file built with RAD. Deploying to other application server (e.g. tomcatEE 
) is possible, but it would require some work.  OpenLiberty should be closest to the IBM Websphere in terms of setup and architecture.

Here are some links that provide more information.

[OpenLiberty](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty)

[IBM announces Open Liberty, an open source runtime for Java microservices](https://jaxenter.com/ibm-announces-open-liberty-support-java-microservices-cloud-native-apps-137349.html)

[Difference between OpenLiberty and Websphere Liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306036/what-is-the-difference-between-openliberty-and-websphere-liberty)